# Mongoose aggregate pipeline date greater than query with bson varible

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Actually, I am raising this question after trying previous questions answers. but, I don't find any clue that's why I am asking

Trying to achieve:

In mongoose aggregation, I am using pipeline aggregation to get documents from the collection by the following query

```
$match: {
  $and: [
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: ["$device_id", "$$device_id"]
      }
    },
    {
      date: {
        "$gte": "$billing_cycle_startdate",
        "$lte": endOfDay
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

billing_cycle_startdate will be : 2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z  by following query

```
{
  $addFields: {
    billing_cycle_startdate: {
      $concat: [
        year, "-", month, "-", "$device_details.billing_cycle"
      ]
    },
  }
},
{ $set: { billing_cycle_startdate: {  $toDate: "$billing_cycle_startdate" } }},
```

but this query returns empty results

if I run

```
{
  date: {
    "$gte": new Date("2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "$lte": endOfDay
  }
}
```

it returns results as expected

is there is any other way to convert 2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z to queryable format without using **new Date()** function and also want to know what is the difference between **2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z** and **new Date("2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z")**

There is any other way to achieve this query??

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: If there are no results at all, it must be the match stage is exluding everything.  Can we see a sample document and the full pipeline?

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I found what's wrong with my query. it's just a syntax error to use the variable @Joe

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a few days of suffering, I found what's wrong with my query

I just forget to use let syntax in my pipeline to specify a variable which is **billing_cycle_startdate** and forget to use it in the pipeline field stage

> The pipeline cannot directly access the input document fields.
> Instead, first, define the variables for the input document fields,
> and then reference the variables in the stages in the pipeline.

for more: [click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-join-let)

then I changed my query as follows

```
   {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "name",
                    let: {
                        device_id: "$budget.device",
                        billing_cycle_startdate: "$billing_cycle_startdate"
                    },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        $expr: {
                                            $eq: ["$device_id", "$$device_id"]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $and: [
                                            {
                                                $expr: {
                                                    $gte: ["$date", "$$billing_cycle_startdate"],
                                                },
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $expr: {
                                                    $lte: ["$date", endOfDay],
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: "dailyenergylogs"
                }
            },
```